# High-quality PDF to Word conversion in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word

What's the best way of converting PDF docs to Microsoft Word format in PHP?  This can be either as a PHP script or calling a (Linux) executable (with proc_open()).  It just needs to be relatively fast and produce quality Word documents (in 97/2000/2003 format).

Commercial software is OK.

Comment: did you ever get the solution?

Answer (score 8):

To read **PDF** files, you will need to install the **[XPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/about.html)** package, which includes "pdftotext." Once you have XPDF/pdftotext installed, you run the following PHP statement to get the PDF text:

```
content = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext '.$filename.' -');
```

After getting the content, Download **[PHPDOCX](http://www.phpdocx.com/)** Community version, try like this.

```
<?php
require_once '../../classes/CreateDocx.inc';

$docx = new CreateDocx();
$textInfo = $content;

$paramsTextInfo = array(
    'val' => 1,
    'i' => 'single',
    'sz' => 8
);

$docx->addText($textInfo, $paramsTextInfo);

$docx->createDocx('report.docx');
?>
```

Comment: It will loose its formatting. Just conversion is not concerned, how to keep the formatting too?

Answer (score 0):

Openoffice has a [PDF import extension](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Pdf_Import_Extension). Most of OpenOffice is scriptable, so you should be able to write a command line interface to perform the conversion. There are many [examples](http://udk.openoffice.org/python/python-bridge.html#examples) on the official UNO wiki.

Answer (score -1):

Another option for the conversion is [Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for PHP](https://products.aspose.cloud/words/php). It is an efficient set of Word document processing solutions without any Microsoft Word dependencies. It is paid product but free pricing plan offers 150 free API calls monthly.

```
<?php

require_once('D:\xampp\htdocs\aspose-words-cloud-php-master\vendor\autoload.php');


try {

    //TODO: Get your ClientID and ClientSecret at https://dashboard.aspose.cloud (free registration is required).       
    $ClientSecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $ClientID="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx";


    $wordsApi = new Aspose\Words\WordsApi($ClientID,$ClientSecret);
    
    
    $format = "docx";
    $file = ("C:/Temp/02_pages.pdf");
    
    $request = new Aspose\Words\Model\Requests\ConvertDocumentRequest($file, $format,null);
    $result = $wordsApi->ConvertDocument($request); 
    copy($result->getPathName(),"C:/Temp/02_pages.docx");
        
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo  "Something went wrong: ",  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

P.S: I'm developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @hassanrazadev yes, it preserves the formatting.

Answer (score -3):

By far the easiest way is with phpLiveDocx. It can load DOC, DOCX and RTF and save to PDF. It can be downloaded from http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/brief-introduction-to-phplivedocx/ The download file contains a large number of sample applications, which illustrate all aspects of the PHP5 library. Leo

Comment: this does the opposite of what they want!