# how to convert pdf to word using php

Tags: php

> convert PDF to word document

like.doc/.docx.
I was trying with PHPWord library but no way to do it properly.

```
<?php
include  'vendor/autoload.php';
include_once 'class.filetotext.php';
    $reader = new Filetotext("test.pdf");
    $file = $reader->convertToText();

    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();


    $section = $phpWord->addSection();

    $section->addText(
        $file
    );

    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'docx');
    $objWriter->save('helloWorld.pdf');
?>
```

Like this I can get only text content of the pdf and convert it to doc or docx . But the image content and styling getting removed. I need a same content word document . Please help me by providing some way. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Then use another library to read pdf files, like [this](http://www.pdfparser.org/) one.

Comment: well this is the same I have tried this also

Comment: Why does one want to create a MS-Word document these days?!?

Comment: this is my project requirement :)

Comment: Then perhaps try converting your pdf to [HTML](https://github.com/mgufrone/pdf-to-html), and from HTML to [DOC](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord).

Comment: yes I was trying the same :) but I am not able to use the 1st one

Comment: @IshaqueJaved did you solve it? Please share some ideas if you solved it.

Comment: You may try other option like Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for PHP. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437716/high-quality-pdf-to-word-conversion-in-php/65196307#65196307).